# Sum of nth root of unity implies everything equals 1

Tags: complex-numbers, galois-theory, absolute-value, roots-of-unity, galois-extensions

Assume $K$ is algebraically closed and $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$. Let $n$ be a positive integer. Assume we have $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_m$ $n$th roots of unity with the property $\lambda_1 +...+\lambda_m =m$. Show that all $\lambda_i =1$.

How can we prove this? Is there any method using Galois theory (acting via elements of the galois group) or is it possible to go back to the case $K=\mathbb{C}$ via some isomorphism and then using the absolute value of complex numberes?
Other ideas are also welcome!

Comment: Just embed the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$ in $K$ into $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Yeah you are right, that's possible. So the above question reduces to $K=\mathbb{C}$ , which should not be that hard to solve.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity in $K$ then the problem lives in the subfield $\Bbb{Q}(\lambda)$ of $K$ and mapping that isomorphically into a cyclotomic subfield of $\Bbb{C}$ is an obvious way forward. Using automorphisms of $K$ may or may not work. Subtleties like the following may ruin your day: if we drop the axiom of choice it is possible that $\Bbb{C}$ (or $K$) only has a single non-trivial automorphism, namely the complex conjugation. Topological completion kills a lot of automorphisms :-)

Comment: Hey, why should we consider dropping the AC? It is used everywhere.